# vue.js how can i use axios .get my code is doesnt working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

i want use axios.get and get some data in my database but it have a error.

this is my store.js code

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    test: null
  },
  mutations: {
    testt(state, payload) {
      state.test = payload;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    testFun({ commit }) {
      axios.get("http://localhost:8070/beer").then(response => {
        let test = {
          id: response.data.data.id,
          title: response.data.data.title,
          subtitle: response.data.data.subtitle
        };
        commit("testt", test);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

this is my app.vue code

```js
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  props: {
    source: String
  },
  data: () => ({
    drawer: null
  }),
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["isLogin"])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(["testFun"])
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
     <v-list-item router :to="{name: 'test'}" exact @click="testFun()">
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-icon>mdi-contact-mail</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-action>
          <v-list-item-content>
            <v-list-item-title>test</v-list-item-title>
          </v-list-item-content>
        </v-list-item>
```

this.is my testt.vue code

```js
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(["test"])
  },
  data() {
    return {
      beer: []
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    //
  }
};
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Beer List</h1>
    <div v-for="beer in test" :key="beer.id">{{ beer.title }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
```

and i have router 
and my database is no problem because i texting path in my controller path it was working but it doesn't woring on vue

but result is error
this is errormessage
TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

Comment: The code you've posted has nothing to do with java, spring or postgres. If the problem is a serverside error, you'd need to post the server code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brother in your back-end request the title variable are not exist in your json response kindly check and let me know. if you still facing any issue.

Thanks

Comment: I solved! it was my falut. i didn't run my vue project. i dont know i have to run two server. now i know why it need 2 server one is back-end server the other is fornt server

Comment: Good Brother use Git Bash.. Or use Vs Code IDE in which you can Use its multiple terminal.